# How to test with parametrize that something is None or not None?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, nonetype

I have a method that shall return `None` in some exceptional situations and otherwise something "complicated".
In my dummy MWE below (not my real method!) there are two situations (`x==0` and `x==10`) where `None` is returned.

```
    def foo(x: int) -> typing.Optional[float]:
    if x == 0 or x == 10:
        return None
    else:
        return 1/x
```

I have a unittest to test the "complicated" outcome in detail for "normal" situations. Now, I want to write a test specifically about whether the method returns `None` for the exceptional situations and something which is `not None` for the normal situation

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("x, target",
                     [(0, None), (10, None), (5, not None)])
def test_foo(x, target):
    assert foo(x) is target
```

I hoped to have a test case `assert foo(5) is not None`, but the variable `target` which was `not None` is evaluated as `True` and thus `assert foo(x) is True` will fail.
**So how to test with parametrize that something is `None` or `not None`?**

Comment: you definitely should use [hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for stuff like that ! it's excellent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the desired condition in a function and call that on the result?

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("x, validator",[0, lambda x: x is None])
def test_foo(x, validator):
    assert validator(foo(x))
```

Of course, you can have two real functions `is_none` and `not_none`.  Signals intent clearly enough.

Alternatively, put some custom logic in your test fn, and use an Enum with two entries `NONE` and `NOT_NONE` to signal intent.

Or most simply, just write the test explicitly:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("x, is_none", [0, False])
def test_foo_returns_none(x, is_none):
    res = foo(x)
    if is_none:
        assert res is None
    else:
        assert res is not None
```

With all that said, you really should look at hypothesis as the answer says.  It can be a fiddle to set up for some functions, but it's a really great tool.  It can also be used to find pathological cases, which is otherwise pretty hard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should really take a look at [hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):
(just run `pytest` as usual to test)

```
from hypothesis import given 
import hypothesis.strategies as st


def foo(x: int) -> typing.Optional[float]:
    if x == 0 or x == 10:
        return None
    else:
        return 1/x
    
@given(x=st.integers(min_value=14))
def test_foo(x: int) -> None:
    assert foo(x) is not None
```

Here I added a precondition that if the integer is at least 14 then `foo` will *not* return `None`. Similarly you can add various preconditions easily, and get the benefit of working with *symbolic* values rather than *concrete* examples (needed to be written manually)

Comment: this is not *quite* what the OP wanted: shouldn't you write a strategy like `one_of(st.integers(min_value=1, max_value=9), st.integers(min_value=11)?  But hypothesis is great.

Comment: @2e0byo the `>= 14` is just an example. I'm basically arguing that if one finds oneself writing `(received, expected)` pairs manually - hypothesis is definitely worth a visit.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about hypothesis. Even if I cannot solve my question solely on your answer, I will have a look :)